# Is python server side or client side?

Tags: php, python, javascript

I am debating on using python or work with JavaScript & PHP.

Basically what I am trying to do is run an algorithm against some data pulled from my database. ( the algorithm can be very demanding on the server so I would want to put the algorithm on the client side).

Hopefully that makes sense.

Also, I am planning for large traffic on my website.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a server side language and can be programmed to interact with client side languages such as Javascript. Python has a great framework named Django that can make these interactions more streamlined. You can learn more about Django here: https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: so to e clear.. if i was to have python running an algorithm against data pulled from the database it would slow the server down?

Comment: The computation that the server is doing would be relying on the CPU power of the server. So depending on how well the program is written, it could bog the server down, or run well if the code was efficiently written. You can have another server dedicated just for computational tasks, and the web pages themselves served via a different server as to not slow down the serving of the actual pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you need, you can to run python on the client.

Many apps on linux are desktop applications, not web applications.

Try to look a gui library for python:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

If you not want to install more libraries, you can use the native python library tkInter:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Answer (score 0):

What makes a language client-side is the browser. I don't think it's correct to say "python is client/server side", as it doesnt depend on the language.

So the browsers run javascript only, so it they cant interpret python directly. There exist some tool that will let you write python for client side (which compile to js). Take a look at [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/).

Another question that comes up is Why use python? Why not just write it in javascript instead of using some unknown tool?